# Proving a polynomial is irreducible over a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I would like to prove that x² + 2x - 1 is irreducible over ℤ/5ℤ.

Not really sure how to go with that, it's probably related to finding roots in the field since it's already monic, right ?

Thank you.

Comment: A quadratic (or cubic) is irreducible if and only if it has no root in the field.

Comment: Your polynomial is $(x+1)^2-2$ and $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if a quadratic is reducible, then it factors into two linear factors, so it has at least one root (possibly repeated).

So you can just plug in every number to see if it has a root.

Comment: So, 0 gives -1 or 4 mod 5, 1 gives 2 mod 5, 2 gives 2 mod 5, 3 gives 4 mod 5, 4 gives 3 mod 5 and that's it ?

Comment: Could you please check and try to answer my other question about equation in fields ?